# MatLab Group by Non-Descending Order

Tags: matlab, group-by

In MatLab 2016b, is there a way to group the values of the below vector by non-descending order?

```
values = [1 1 1 7 17 74 89 91 96 1 5 32 43 78 84 95 98 100 0 0 15 31 69 88 94 97 100 100 100 0 2 12 42 66 78 83 89 94 97 1 6 34 63 65 75 89 93 98]
```

so I will get the following groups:

group A) 1 1 1 7 17 74 89 91 96

group B) 1 5 32 43 78 84 95 98 100

group C) 0 0 15 31 69 88 94 97 100 100 100

group D) 0 2 12 42 66 78 83 89 94 97

group E) 1 6 34 63 65 75 89 93 98

Comment: Have you tried `reshape`?

Comment: Not at all. How?

Comment: https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html?requestedDomain=true

Comment: @Hazem `reshape` can convert a linear vector to a rectangular matrix, but that's not what the question asks for - the groups do not all have the same number of elements.

Comment: @nekomatic My bad, I did not realize that groups don't have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff(values)
```

returns a vector with the difference between each element of `values` and the following element. We can use this in a comparison to give a logical vector:

```
diff(values) < 0
```

returns a vector containing `true`, or 1, whenever the corresponding element of `values` is less than the following element. To finish the job we can use the `cumsum` function which returns a vector containing the running total of the elements in the input vector:

```
groups = cumsum([1, diff(values) < 0])
```

Just one wrinkle: we have to prepend an extra element at the front of the `diff` vector, because it has one fewer element than `values` did. Now we have a vector `groups` containing 1 for each element of `values` that should be in the first group, 2 for each element that should be in the second group, and so on.

You can access the individual groups using logical indexing:

```
values(groups == n) % returns a vector of the values in group n
```

If you want the groups as separate vectors you could use `arrayfun`:

```
groupArray = arrayfun(@(x) values(groups == x), 1:max(groups), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

This returns a cell array where `groupArray{1}` is the first group, `groupArray{2}` is the second group, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should give you what you are looking for:

```
% Define the values...
values = [1 1 1 7 17 74 89 91 96 1 5 32 43 78 84 95 98 100 0 0 15 31 69 88 94 97 100 100 100 0 2 12 42 66 78 83 89 94 97 1 6 34 63 65 75 89 93 98];

% Define the linear indices...
subs = 1:numel(values);

% Define the grouping indices...
idx = [0 subs(diff(values) < 0) subs(end)];

% Split the values into multiple arrays...
result = arrayfun(@(k)values(idx(k-1)+1:idx(k)),2:numel(idx),'UniformOutput',false);
```

Here is the final output:

```
>> result{:}

ans =
      1     1     1     7    17    74    89    91    96
ans =
      1     5    32    43    78    84    95    98   100
ans =
      0     0    15    31    69    88    94    97   100   100   100
ans =
      0     2    12    42    66    78    83    89    94    97
ans =
      1     6    34    63    65    75    89    93    98
```